# ¿Como eliminar datos sobre-almacenados en una lista? Python

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en esto y se me pidió crear una lista de registro en python donde se vayan almacenado datos y que según códigos(rut) este pueda ser eliminado el problema es que no encuentro la manera de eliminar solo algunos datos sin vaciar la lista entera ayuda adjunto código:

```
lista=[]
class Alumno:
  rut=""
  nombre=""
  edad=0

def registraralumno():
  print("Registrar Alumno")
  a= Alumno()
  a.rut = input("Ingrese rut: ")
  a.nombre = input("Ingrese nombre: ")
  a.edad= int(input("Ingrese edad: "))
  lista.append(a)
def listaralumno():
  print("Lista de alumnos")
  for a in lista:
    print (a.rut,"-",a.nombre,"-",a.edad)
def buscaralumno():
  print("Busqueda de alumno")
  rut=input("Ingrese rut")
  for a in lista:
      if a.rut== rut:
        nv=input("Ingrese nuevo rut")
        a.rut=nv
        nn=input("Ingrese nombre")
        a.nombre=nn
        break
def removeralumno():
  print("remover de alumno")
  rut=input("Ingrese rut")
  for a in lista:
      if a.rut== rut:
        del(a.rut,a.nombre,a.edad)
        print("thx")



def menu():
  while True:
    print("Menú")
    print("1.-Registrar alumno")
    print("2.-Listar alumnos")
    print("3.-Buscar alumno")
    print("4.-Remover lista")
    op=int(input("Digite Opcion "))
    if op==1:
      registraralumno()
    elif op==2:
      listaralumno()
    elif op==3:
      buscaralumno()
    elif op==4:
      removeralumno()
menu()
```

Ejecutando ese programa me da por resultado en un primer lugar 2 espacios vacíos y uno en 0 al ser un int pero necesito que se eliminen del sistema esos datos y quede como primer lugar el segundo registrado

Comment: El método "del" debes darle  el indice que vas a eliminar: del lista[lista.index(a)]

Comment: Por otro lado tu clase Alumno está mal definida. Deberia ser o jeto. Voy a escribir la respuesta mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes  que corregir algunas cosas:

1. La clase Alumno: como las has definido las propiedades rut, nombre y edad pertenecen a la clase. Por lo tanto,cada alumno que agregas a la lista tendrá la información del último alumno ingresado, es decir, cada vez que ingresas un alumno a la lista se modifican todos de la lista por este último. Ya que estas utilizando variables de clase.  Para que esto no suceda crea la clase con propiedades de objeto:

   ```
     class Alumno:

       def __init__(self, p_rut,p_nombre,p_edad):
           self.rut=p_rut
           self.nombre=p_nombre
           self.edad=p_edad
   ```
2. Cuando agregues un alumno, debes primero recabar los datos y luego añadir el objeto a la lista:

   ```
        rut=input.......
        nombre=input....
        edad=input....  
        lista.append(Alumno(rut,nombre,edad))
   ```
3. Para eliminar debes modificar el "del":

   ```
     del lista[lista.index(a)]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes aplicar la función [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), por ejemplo:

```
def removeralumno():
  print("remover de alumno")
  rut=input("Ingrese rut")
  lista = list(filter(lambda alumno: alumno.rut != rut, lista))
```

Básicamente se crea una nueva lista con todos los alumnos tal que su código `rut` es distinto del que se quiere borrar.